# How should be test with phpunit for xss + sql injection?

Tags: php, automated-tests, xss, phpunit, sql-injection

How should be test with phpunit php web application for xss + sql injection?
I thinking to find program that output xss+ other attacks to test my application forms.
This program/service should be all time updated with new xss and other new attacks.
Does such service/program exist, if not how it done today?
Please give some examples if you can.

(I use php 5.3 + zend framework + mysql)

---

Edit:

I asking about testing!and not prevent techniques that I also know.

Thanks,

Yosef

Comment: Not sure whether this is a case for Unit Testing at all... Interested to see what answers come up.

Comment: I'm tempted to answer, 'Write a script looking for "(SELECT|INSERT|UPDATE) .*\$\w+.*", if that is present, your code has failed.'

Comment: I'll agree, this isn't about unit testing, this is about making sure that your code only uses prepared-statements. Use the PDO system, and then bind the variables through that system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you can easily do unit tests for this kind of thing. It would require that your application is written in a way conducive to mocking its component parts and definitely involve a great deal of continuous manual work (making sure there's tests and mocks for everything, testing for the myriad flavors of attacks, etc etc).

The only certain thing is that if you can get some automated tool of broad scope that's always up-to-date, whoever gave it to you didn't charge enough.

The forms of protecting against such attacks are pretty well known and easy to utilize:

- Always [escape variables in sql](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), or better yet use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
- If you do not *need* to accept and preserve HTML input, always `htmlspecialchars` any variable that goes into HTML (note that there are many formats such as [BBCode](http://www.bbcode.org/), [MarkDown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), [Textile](http://textile.thresholdstate.com/) etc whose sole purpose is to allow a useful subset of formatting options without opening Pandora's box)
- If you *absolutely, most certainly need* to accept, store and serve HTML data then there's [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) that can help -- but do that only as a last resort

Therefore, I 'd say that it's much better value for your time to make sure that you follow these practices/use these tools.

Furthermore, if you funnel all access to these two subsystems (sql and HTML output) through a well-defined part of your application (database access methods that escape all input no matter what; HTML output functions that in the same manner escape input variables and inject them into a provided "HTML template" that you subsequently echo) then it becomes easy to unit test these subsystems. Decent PHP frameworks already do this.

At this point, the only real chance of introducing a vulnerability is by circumverting or misusing these subsystems. In my opinion you are better off spending effort on specifying and following good coding practices that writing unit tests to prevent vulnerabilities in your business logic (unit tests for you sanitization code are of course another thing entirely).

Finally, there are [automated](http://code.google.com/p/bsqlhacker/) [SQL](http://sqlmap.sourceforge.net/) [injection](http://sqlninja.sourceforge.net/) [tools](http://sqlsus.sourceforge.net/) and [XSS-related](http://xsser.sourceforge.net/) [tools](http://xss.codeplex.com/) that you can use to probe web applications. But unless someone hires you to do penetration testing, it's better to use these as you would use protection in sex: use it, but don't count on it.

Comment: Downvoter: Please help me improve the answer if you find it deficient. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I would not write unit tests for XSS or SQL injection detection.
What I would do is:

To prevent XSS, escape all user output with one of:

- [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)
- [filter extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) (PHP 5.2+)
- [escape](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.view.introduction.html) (Zend Framework)
- http://htmlpurifier.org/ (External
  library)

To prevent SQL Injection, use [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and placeholders for everything.
ie)

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $_POST['id']";
```

becomes

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = ?";
```

or

```
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = :id";
```

**Edit**
You might also want to try some browser addons such as:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hackbar/
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xss-me/
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sql-inject-me/
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/access-me/

Comment: I know how prevent, I asking about testing

Comment: @Yosef You might want to try a browser extension to test for vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks, does this extension require insert test manually?because this not solve the problem

Answer (score 5):

SQL injections are one of those classes of problems that can only really be found by auditing your code. You should be looking for places where you're dynamically building queries rather than using prepared statements - those are your SQL injection vectors. Change those to prepared statements, and you remove the risk of SQL injection.

Unit testing will help you with logic errors, but won't help you find security problems such as that. The only solutions are vigilance and code reviews/audits.

UPDATE: I almost forgot! You should check out [PHP_CodeSniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/) for doing automated auditing of your code. It should help you detect at least *some* instances of where people are doing potentially dangerous and insecure things in code, and you can extend it to detect more problems than the basic install will by default.

Comment: +1 for code audits being the best solution.  But prepared statements are not proof against all cases of SQL injection.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by that. I'm working under the assumption that if somebody's using prepared statements they're also (a) checking the user has access to the record being selected/inserted/updated/deleted and (b) that the statements themselves aren't being constructed dynamically. I can't think of any other obvious SQL injection vectors possible with prepared statements. There's the possibility of the server caching suboptimal execution plans, but that's really a separate problem. For my own curiosity, could elaborate on other injection vectors prepared statements wouldn't cover?

Comment: @Keith: Query parameters can be used in place of a literal SQL value, and only one-for-one.  People still have the need to make other parts of a query dynamic, for instance a table name, column name, SQL keywords, list of values in an `IN( )` clause, or other expressions.  You can't use query parameters for those cases, so you have to build the SQL query string with application logic prior to preparing the query against the RDBMS.

Comment: For more information, see my presentation http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies, or my book "SQL Antipatterns" (http://www.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/sql-antipatterns).

Comment: Yes, I'd forgotten about that. Funnily enough, years back I wrote a function in PHP that wrapped mysql_query() to fake the effect of prepared statements. It took this into account, and if a placeholder was in a position where a list of values could be taken, it would accept an array of scalar values and safely quote and escape them.

Comment: I've never understood why most DB APIs don't do something similar given all the information is right there in the query's text. The rest can only realistically be caught using code audits unfortunately.

Comment: Did you handle character sets correctly?  Keep in mind that PHP regular expressions know nothing about character sets. See http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: Yes, of course. I'm Irish, and that makes me rather acutely aware that all the world is not ASCII, especially so when one works for a company with customers from all over the EU and have to cleanly deal with three different alphabets.

Answer (score 2):

Use frameworks like [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Get the [XSS Me add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/xss-me/) for firefox and run it against your pages to test.